# Obstáculo vison enemigo unity2D

Tags: c#, unity3d

Presento el siguiente problema, estoy haciendo un juego en 2D top down game  donde el enemigo tenga un rango de visión, pero  lo que me interesa es hacer es que el rango de visión sea limitado por algún obstáculo que haya al frente de player, por ejemplo si el player esta delante de una piedra  este no pueda verle.

estoy intentándolo con [Physics2D.Raycast](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.Raycast.html) pero este ultimo no discrimina de los objetos que hay al frente.

estos son los scripts que he utilizado("cada uno es independiente del otro"):

```
RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, -Vector2.up);
    if ( hit.collider.tag == "Player" ) {
        Debug.Log ("raycast");
    }
```

---

```
spotted = Physics2D.Linecast (sightStar.position,sightheEnd.position, 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("Player"));
```

¿Alguno sabrá como hacer para que el enemigo tenga obstáculos en la visión?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que lo que usted esta buscando puede solucionarlo usando las `LayerMask`
como no se lo que usted sabe al respecto (y yo nunca lo he implemetado en 2D solo en 3D), le dejare algunas notas de lo que creo que puede ayudar y algun ejemplo, pero este es solo como ilustracion:

Lo que le puede ayudar es usar Raycast con LayerMask para filtar los objetos que usted cosidera que son obtaculos mendiante el uso de capas.

En este link puede ver los parametros que acepta (link Ingles)
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.Raycast.html
pero el que recalco es el que admite:

- `layerMask`  Filter to detect Colliders only on certain layers.
- `layerMask`  Filtro para detectar Colliders sólo en determinadas capas.

su uso seria algo asi:

```
RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, Vector2.right, obtaculoMask);
```

obtaculoMask es basicamente un entero al cual se le aplican opereciones a nivel de bits.`bitwise`

Algo como esto:(dependiendo de lo que se quiera obtener esto es un simple ejemplo)

```
int obtaculosLayer = 8;            
int obtaculoMask   = 1 << obtaculosLayer;
```

Te dejo algunos link (ingles) para que puedas echar un vistazo de como funcionan:

http://unity3d-book.blogspot.com.es/2014/03/unity3d-raycast-with-layermask-how-do.html

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/8715/how-do-i-use-layermasks.html

Tambien encontre este video tratando de encontrar algo en español quizas te pueda ayudar y sea mas comodo viendolo en el editor:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LpZO0NoQ2J4

P.D: usted dice enfrente y usa `-Vector2.up`, no esta mal pues el frente, (y mas en un juego depende de muchos factores y de lo que se entienda como frente, solo se lo comento por si en un futuro lo lee en su codigo y piensa que es abajo.

Tambien le puede ayudar el uso de `Debug.DrawRay` le dejo otro link (ingles)
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.DrawRay.html

lo que hace `DrawRay`:

```
public static void DrawRay(Vector3 start, Vector3 dir, Color color = Color.white, float duration = 0.0f, bool depthTest = true);
```

Es dibuja una línea desde start a start + dir con el color que se le especifica (o con el que usara default de no indicar ninguno) tiene mas opciones como la duracion ect (para no entrar en detalles), usted podria usarlo para dibujar rayos y poder verlos en el modo mientras esta haciendo pruebas por ejemplo de la siguiente forma:

```
function Update () {
     Debug.DrawRay (Vector3.zero, transform.position*10, Color.red);
}
```

Vemos que aqui el segundo parametro no es el destino final del rayo, sino la direccion y distancia del rayo veremos una línea de 10 "metros/unidades" saliendo desde el centro de la escena, esto lo puede usar para asignarle las posiciones (por ejemplo empleando transform.position o el que desee) a su "player/enemigos" por ejemplo y la distancia que este tiene de vision asi le sera mas comodo de ver y calcular las distancias que considere apropiadas para su juego de una manera mas visual.

Quizas la respuesta trata varios temas/utilidades y conceptos pero creo que sera de su utilidad tanto ahora como en un futuro.

Comment: Se me presenta un inconveniente resulta que le pongo el  layerMask al script que me mandaste  y me funciona bien y me detecta el  obstaculo bien, pero no me detecta el objeto player sino  hasta que esta demasiado cerca o mejor dicho colisiona  con el objeto enemigo.

Answer (score 3):

Lo más recomendable según [la documentación](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LayerMask.html) es que le pongas una etiqueta a todo lo que quieres que sea un obstáculo, para que por ejemplo si tienes algún objeto como una ventana no lleve su etiqueta `obstáculovisión` pero una pared sí.
El código quedaría algo como:

```
//    capa
var mask : LayerMask = -1;
function Update () {
var hit:Raycast2D =Physics.Raycast (transform.position, Vector2.right, 100, mask.value);
    if (hit !=null) {
        Debug.Log("Hit something");
      if ( hit.collider.tag == "Player" ) {
         Debug.Log ("player seen");
      }else{
        Debug.Log ("obstacle");
      }
    }
}
```

PD: perdona, pero le entiendo más al unityscript que al C#, espero te haya ayudado.

Comment: Si no funciona dime apra hacer mis pruebas. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Esta fue la solución mas practica que logre encontrar las anteriores funcionan genial tambien:

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/629483/get-the-name-of-the-collided-object.html